# Получить список сайтов IIS удаленного сервера

Tags: c#, iis

Пытаюсь получить путь к папке с приложениями на сервере приложений IIS.

```
                var serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote(temp[0]);
                var site = serverManager?.Sites?.FirstOrDefault(it => it.Name == "Default Web Site"); // Тут валимся с NullReference. Решение этой проблемы ниже, но мне оно не подходит.
```

В `temp[0]` — адрес сервера.

Это не работает, т.к. на сервере не настроено удаленное управление конфигурацией.
Для тех, у кого есть доступ к настройкам безопасности сервера, поможет вот это:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2691

У меня такой роскоши нет, несмотря на то, что админская учётка есть (у любого пользователя приложения имеется, если он введёт свои учётные данные в неё, т.к. пользуются приложением из учётной записи обычного пользователя те же люди — такая политика, админский учётки используются только для непосредственной работы на серверах), но менять настройки безопасности мы без согласования не можем (да и не хотим).

Есть ли альтернативные варианты получения сайтов или каталогов приложений, опубликованных на этих сайтах в IIS?

Вообще конечная цель — получить папку с каталогами приложений, опубликованных в IIS. Обычно они публикуются в "Default Web Site", так что сгодится даже костыль для этого конкретного сайта.
По прошлому опыту, это делалось из конфигурации IIS, поэтому в этом ключе и вопрос, но теперь эту возможность прикрыли, поэтому рассмотрю любые альтернативы, даже "костыльные".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для меня решением проблемы, описанной в вопросе, оказался даунгрейд `Microsoft.Web.Administration` до версии 7.0.0. По дефолту установилась 11+.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть админский доступ, тогда вам должна быть доступна папка с конфигурацией ИИСа, в которой и лежит эта информация, и при подключении через локальную сеть можно воспользоваться таким вызовом:

```
string path = @"\\" + IP + @"\C$\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config";
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager(path);
var site = iisManager?.Sites?.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == name);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую! Это должно сработать, судя по всему.

Comment: Решение не помогло, однако исчерпывающая информация, которая меня интересовала, лежала в данном файле, сгодится как воркэраунд, вдруг решу изменить подход. Спасибо ещё раз!